# Drupal 7 and MongoDB module howto

Tags: database

Just installed 7.x-1.0-beta1 to Drupal 7rc1.

Should I see some new option in the configuration? Where should I set the connection settings? I have no idea how to use this module...

Comment: I found a README by poking around in the CVS archive, it looks helpful: http://drupalcode.org/viewvc/drupal/contributions/modules/mongodb/README.txt?revision=1.3&view=markup&pathrev=HEAD

Comment: If the module does not work, I wrote a how-to on syncing Drupal and MongoDB http://www.agnosticdev.com/blog-entry/mongodb/drupal-detachment-drupal-and-mongodb-part-23

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I (and my team) wrote most of that module and -- as Jeremy says, it's only needed for extreme scalability. Because of that, it's supposed you know what you are doing (otherwise you will have no chance of scaling to the levels where MongoDB is necessary) and so no UI is provided, just use $conf overrides.

There's a DBTNG driver too but it's more in a proof-of-concept stage so it's in a separate project.

Comment: Hi chx and thanks for taking the time to answer :) I don't consider myself a Drupal expert, but it only took me a couple of hours to test memcache on my laptop (by following its docs), whereas I couldn't find a single example for your module. My humble suggestion would be to add $conf snippet to your project page, so that people like me can actually try out you great module. On the meanwhile I'll try what Grayside suggests.

Comment: I do not understand, grayside linked to the readme I wrote and it has $conf snippets.

Comment: That link does not work. I also don't see any documentation at http://drupal.org/project/mongodb

Comment: The README.txt is in every download. But, here's a post-git migration (which happened a year ago...) http://drupalcode.org/project/mongodb.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/README.txt link.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a module that you should use unless you have a need to. It can support mongoDB in a number of cases, but doesn’t look like it will totally replace mysql.

Generally you should be looking to use something like mongoDB if you are starting to have scalability problems.

What are you actually trying to do?